# I was a Pro Photographer for over 40 years

Tags: discussion

Could you use help answering questions? I was a pro photographer for over 40 years shooting the Oscars, The Emmy's, weddings etc etc.... I was taught that if you truly are a photographer you should be able to shoot anything. I am trying to give back some of what i was blessed with so I though I would ask
Thank You in advance
Pops

Comment: You don't need to ask permission, just jump in and answer any questions you know the answer to :)  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! The short answer is yes of course. All questions not directly related to photography but this site itself, its users, etc. go on the meta site. (I voted to migrate it there) I'm not sure if you have enough reputation to post there, so take an upvote from me.

Comment: Welcome, and please contribute. To start, click on the 'help' item on the bar at the top, then select 'Tour'. This will give you the basics of how to help. Don't forget, if you don't see something, feel free to ask a question, and then answer your own question!

Comment: But please, use a more personalized name than user46800!

Answer (score 12):

Pops, welcome aboard, and *of course* we could use your help. Stackexchange is about crowd-sourcing information, so the more the merrier.

I'm only a hobbyist photographer and professionally a technical writer, and *I've* been able to contribute.

Because this isn't a messageboard, there's nothing to stop you from looking over the older questions in what you feel to be your areas of expertise, to see if there's an answer you can add that fills in the gaps. That's how I started out, and I ended up gaining reputation pretty rapidly. The more reputation you have, [the more things you can do](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) on the site.

Just take a little time to get acquainted with how Stackexchange works. The Help→[Tour](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/tour) is an excellent place to start.

Answer (score 6):

Anyone can participate, so of course you can.

However, I strongly recommend you properly fill in your user profile, including your name.  Nobody is going to put much stock in what USERxxxx says.  We get a lot of drive-by one-question users like that, so any user with a name like that is much more likely to be dismissed and assumed to be a help vampire than someone willing to stand up and put his reputation behind what he's saying.

Put another way, to be really affective it's not good enough to just be right.  You have to give us some reason to trust that what you say is in fact right.